# show git log starting from HEAD and going in reverse

Tags: git

How do I `git log` starting from HEAD and going in reverse?

So given

```
^ latest
|
24adad3 fourth commit
4c6ff7d Third commit
66d0643 [HEAD] Second commit
7cc0c73 First commit
|
| earliest
```

I want:

```
66d0643 [HEAD] Second commit
4c6ff7d Third commit
24adad3 Fourth commit
|
v    (press enter to show more)
```

---

I am almost there:

`git log --oneline --reverse --all`

All that is missing is to have it start from HEAD.

Comment: What about `git log --oneline --reverse --all HEAD..master` (or whatever your branch name is)? (You might also want to remove the `--all` depending on whether you want to show other branches)

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. I posted the command as the answer since you didn't do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log --oneline --reverse --all HEAD..master`

Does the job, however, one might have to substitute `master` depending on the branch to generate logs to.